# Change minecraft proxy in mod [Java]

Tags: java, proxy, minecraft

Quite a while ago I posted a question about how to use a proxy in minecraft.

To sum most of the question up, I'm working on a mob in which I would like to be able to change the proxy of the JVM whenever I want during the code. I understand that it is easy to just set the proxy when invoking the VM but I want to be able to change it in real-time while in the game so that when I connect to a server my IP is different (this mod is mostly going to be used by people who are parranoid of joining servers and people knowing their IP.

I *have* tried setting System Properties as so:

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "186.116.8.170");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

and also tried doing

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "186.116.8.170");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
```

but none of that worked.

I would appreciate any help given, thanks.

Comment: The minecraft protocol doesn't use HTTP for client/server communication.

Comment: @Todd Well what does it use? :/

Answer (score 0):

minecraft used **netty**, you need to use **mixin** to modify **net.minecraft.network.NetworkManager**
code for 1.8.9 below

```java
@Mixin(NetworkManager.class)
public abstract class MixinNetworkManager {
    @Shadow
    @Final
    public static LazyLoadBase<NioEventLoopGroup> CLIENT_NIO_EVENTLOOP;

    @Overwrite
    public static NetworkManager createNetworkManagerAndConnect(InetAddress address, int serverPort, boolean useNativeTransport) {
        final NetworkManager networkmanager = new NetworkManager(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND);

        Bootstrap bootstrap=new Bootstrap();

        EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup;
        Proxy proxy=ProxyManager.INSTANCE.getProxy();
        if(proxy.type().equals(Proxy.Type.DIRECT)){
            eventLoopGroup=CLIENT_NIO_EVENTLOOP.getValue();
            bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        }else {
            if(!Epoll.isAvailable()||!useNativeTransport){
                System.out.println("Something goes wrong! Maybe you can disable proxy. [Epoll="+Epoll.isAvailable()+", UNT="+useNativeTransport+"]");
            }
            eventLoopGroup=new OioEventLoopGroup(0, (new ThreadFactoryBuilder()).setNameFormat("Netty Client IO #%d").setDaemon(true).build());
            bootstrap.channelFactory(new ProxyOioChannelFactory(proxy));
        }

        bootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup).handler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
            protected void initChannel(Channel channel) {
                try {
                    channel.config().setOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
                } catch (ChannelException var3) {
                    var3.printStackTrace();
                }
                channel.pipeline().addLast("timeout", new ReadTimeoutHandler(30)).addLast("splitter", new MessageDeserializer2()).addLast("decoder", new MessageDeserializer(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND)).addLast("prepender", new MessageSerializer2()).addLast("encoder", new MessageSerializer(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND)).addLast("packet_handler", networkmanager);
            }
        });

        bootstrap.connect(address, serverPort).syncUninterruptibly();

        return networkmanager;
    }
```